# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: [windowHandle] is not a top level window handle solution

Tags: selenium-webdriver, winappdriver

Some people including me were suffering from this issue called "**OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: [windowHandle] is not a top level window handle**".

Answer (score 4):

There are lot of question asked and answered on "how to attach to a **TopLevelWindow**" but literally none is talking on "how to attach to a **NonTopLevelWindow**". I searched a lot for a solution but there was nothing on it. But after reading a code shared in this [answer](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/issues/894#issuecomment-545836008) on GitHub, I realized what the solution is.
I was so disgusted after it because of the simplicity of the solution! Then I thought to share it with everyone.
The solution is so simple. As the new window which is a **Child Node** (i.e. resides under the main application tree), **we can not attach to it by creating a new session**. The reason is that, it is not a top level window and we can only attach to a top level window with [this process](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/blob/master/Docs/FAQ.md#when-and-how-to-attach-to-an-existing-app-window) explained on GitHub.
What we need to do is just simply **search for the window by its name** and you will get access of that window (same as finding an UI element)
For example- This code is for such a window which is a **TopLevelWindow**:

```
# create a desktop session to find the new window
desired_caps = {}
desired_caps["app"] = "Root"
newDriver = webdriver.Remote(WindowsApplicationDriverUrl, desired_caps)

# Find the NativeWIndowHandle of the new window
newWindow = newDriver.find_element_by_name("SmarTTY - New SSH Connection")
newWindowHandle = newWindow.get_attribute("NativeWindowHandle")

# create a new session to attach the new window with its NativeWindowHandle
desired_caps = {}
desired_caps["appTopLevelWindow"] = newWindowHandle
connWinDriver = webdriver.Remote(WindowsApplicationDriverUrl, desired_caps)
```

And this code is for such a window which is a **NonTopLevelWindow**:

```
# Find the new window
newPopUpWindow = driverMain.find_element_by_name("SmarTTY - New SSH Connection")
```

In this case the first code will not work due to the window is not being a top level window. But the second code will work.

This window (window name is **SmarTTY - New SSH Connection**) pops open after I click a button on the previous window. The application name on which this example is based on is **SmarTTY**. And the above codes are Python codes for **WinAppDriver**.

Comment: The topLevelWindow mechanism gives us a few other advantages like creating a session out of it and once a session is created it is easy to do manipulations like "newSessionByName.close()" will close the top level window. I feel like when it is not a top level window we miss out on these advantages. I am clicking on cancel, ok etc to dismiss the popup.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my C# code, I am adding it as desired capabilities are depricated and **options** should be used instead:

```
    AppiumOptions rootSessionOptions = new AppiumOptions();
    rootSessionOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("app", "Root");
    rootSessionOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName", "WindowsPC");
    _driver = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), rootSessionOptions);
    _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

    var VSWindow = _driver.FindElementByName("Your project name without .csproj - Microsoft Visual Studio");
    var VSTopLevelWindowHandle = VSWindow.GetAttribute("NativeWindowHandle");
    VSTopLevelWindowHandle = (int.Parse(VSTopLevelWindowHandle)).ToString("x");

    AppiumOptions VisualStudioSessionOptions = new AppiumOptions();
    VisualStudioSessionOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("appTopLevelWindow", VSTopLevelWindowHandle);
    _driver = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), VisualStudioSessionOptions);

    _driver.SwitchTo().Window(_driver.WindowHandles[0]);
```

Comment: This is the code for a topLevelwindow or for a "nonTopLevelWindow"?

Comment: This is for a topLevelwindow. NonTopLevelWindow can be found similar to VSWindow - after you have attached to the topLevelWindow and similar to Shabbir's second code snippet :   

var NonTopLevelWindow= _driver.FindElementByName("Your window name");

Answer (score 0):

```
    # After login i am not able to perform any operation 
#Conftest file code 
import pytest
from appium import webdriver


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def setUp(request):

desired_caps = {}
desired_caps["app"] = r"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Giesecke Devrient\\Compass VMS\\Compass VMS.exe"
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4723',
                          desired_capabilities= desired_caps)
#driver.implicitly_wait(10)
request.cls.driver = driver
yield
    driver.close()


#Main Code  
    from appium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
    from Utility.Base import BaseClass
    
    
    # @pytest.mark.usefixtures("setUp")
    class TestDe_Login(BaseClass):
    
        def test_initialize(self):
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@Name='Login']//*[@LocalizedControlType='text' "
                                              "and @Name='User ID:']/..//*[@LocalizedControlType='edit']").send_keys("t2")
            self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id("passwordTextBox").send_keys("1")
            self.driver.find_element_by_name ("&Login").click()
wait = WebDriverWait(self.newDriver, 20)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, '&Logout'))).click()[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30536180)