# Cannot switch to another window after it found using desktop session due to not TopLevelWindow handle webexception error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, ui-automation, winappdriver

Help is needed, I am struggling to automate a certain scenario in my automation.
Brief background:

- Automating a winform application using WInAppDriver/Appium.
- Using Specflow's BDD to define tests
- At every start of test the automation test will always check if App
  is open already, if not, then fire-up/initialised application
- In that InitializedAppium(string application) we create "a new
  instance of the WindowsDriver class using the specified remote
  address and Appium options".
- Using WinAppDriver & ChromeDriver to execute test.

The test scenario:

1. Test to fire up the Application twice simultaneously.
2. First App instance will have splash screen and open a window asking user to database upgrade. The 2nd App instance will also have splash screen but this time with a window prompting user Application duplication and is sitting on top of the 1st instance App.
3. I can click OK button on the window on the 2nd App instance. then the 1st App instance re-appear
4. I now want to click OK on this database upgrade window in the 1st App instance. But i am struggling.

[image]

I manage to see and find the window in question using  but couldnt attach to it at all! it threw some error that says 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: [windowHandle] is not a top level window handle'

I tried to follow this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62549778/openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-windowhandle-is-not-a-top-level-window-han` but to no avail.

How do i get to find the window in question and interact with it. anyone can point me to the right direction? Regards.

sample Code below:

```
// At this point, IC app is fired up twice simultanouesly. 
// If so, the Database upgrade window appears then a second or two later, another IC instance appear with Duplicate Instance form appear. 
// We need to take action as follow; 
// Go to the top level window [duplicate instance] find the form and OK button element, click OK. 
// It will then closed and reveal the original IC instance with Database Upgrade window.
// Switch to this and click Yes button element.

private bool IsICOpen()
    {
        DebugOutput.Log($"Proc - IsICOpen ", OutputLevel.Procedure);
        int timer = 30;
        bool onPage = false;
        int counter = 1;
        while (!onPage && counter < timer)
        {
            DebugOutput.Log($"WE have windows driver");
            var session = SeleniumUtilities.GetWindowsDriver();

            if (session == null)
            {
                DebugOutput.Log($"We have no recorded Window Driver!");
                GivenSteps.GivenIHaveFailed("Session is Null");
            }
            else
            {
                // get the top window
                var allWindowHandles = session.WindowHandles;
                if (allWindowHandles.Count > 0)
                {
                    DebugOutput.Log($"Number of window handles = {allWindowHandles.Count}");
                    counter = 0;
                    foreach (string windowItem in allWindowHandles)
                    {
                        DebugOutput.Log($"Window Handle is called: {windowItem}");
                    }
                    session.SwitchTo().Window(allWindowHandles[0]);
                    DebugOutput.Log($"Window switch to {allWindowHandles[0]}");
                }
            }
            DebugOutput.Log($"___ IsIcOpen method loop number: {counter} ___");
            
            if (Helpers.Page.ConfirmOnPage("Duplicate Instance", 1))
            {
                DebugOutput.Log(">>> We are hitting IC's Duplicate Instance form <<<");
                try
                {
                    DebugOutput.Log("Clicking on OK button in the Duplicate Instance window.");
                    WhenSteps.WhenIClickOnButton("OK"); // this is working as expected
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    DebugOutput.Log("Clicking on OK button succeeded");
                    SeleniumUtilities.TakeDesktopScreenGrab();
                }
                catch
                {
                    DebugOutput.Log("Failed to click OK button in Duplicate Instance window");
                    GivenSteps.GivenIHaveFailed("Stopping Test");
                }


                try
                {
                    // I have to somehow switch focus to Database Upgrade window from here on.
                    var desktopSession = SeleniumUtilities.GetDesktopDriver();
                    if (desktopSession == null)
                    {
                        DebugOutput.Log($"Our GetDesktop Driver is not working!");
                        return false;
                    }
                    var icWindow = desktopSession.FindElementByClassName("#32770"); // The programme can see this element without a problem
                    var icTopLevelWindowHandle = icWindow.GetAttribute("NativeWindowHandle");
                    DebugOutput.Log($"IC's Database Upgrade window = {icWindow.Text}");
                    DebugOutput.Log($"Found native window called {icTopLevelWindowHandle}");
                    icTopLevelWindowHandle = (int.Parse(icTopLevelWindowHandle)).ToString("x"); // Convert to Hex
                    SeleniumUtilities.SetWindowsDriver(icTopLevelWindowHandle); // This is where the WebDriverException will throw and caught in catch below.
                }
                catch
                {
                    DebugOutput.Log("Someting went wrong trying to switch to ");
                    //GivenSteps.GivenIHaveFailed("Stopping Test");
                }                   
            }
            
            if (Helpers.Page.ConfirmOnPage("Database Upgrade",1))
            {
                Helpers.Page.PageGrab("Database Upgrade");
                WhenSteps.WhenIClickOnButton("Yes");
                GivenSteps.GivenIWaitSeconds(3);
                //WhenSteps.WhenIClickOnButton("OK"); //this seems to throw error: WebDriverException: An element command failed because the referenced element is no longer attached to the DOM.
                WhenSteps.WhenIPressKey("Enter");
                GivenSteps.GivenIWaitSeconds(10);
            }

            DebugOutput.Log($"___ End of IsICOpen loop number {counter} ___");
            counter++;
            ThenSteps.ThenIWaitSeconds(1);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: seems like you'd need two separate drivers for this.  You don't show that part of the code, but it sounds like you're blasting the first instance of "session".  Once you close that 2nd window, your driver has no handle.

Comment: thanks for the pointer @pcalkins - right i hacked it with the following and worked to my desired result. Although it doesn't look very good or tidy - although I am no developer :/

--> create new dektop session to find the 2nd instance window, once found, click OK
--> then, i create another new desktop session to find the 1st instance window, once found, continue test.